# How to initialize parameter search_view_id of ir.actions.act_window in python

Tags: python, odoo

I call this python method through button in xml

```
def plots(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    product = self.env['product.product'].search([('product_tmpl_id','=',self.id)])
    domain = [('type', '=', 'is_plot')]
    return {
        'name': _('Plots'),
        'res_model': 'product.template',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'domain': domain,
        'view_mode': 'kanban,tree,form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'search_view_id': ,
        'help': _('''<p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
                    Plots of Land....</p>'''),
        'context': "{'default_res_model': '%s','default_res_id': %d}" % (self._name, self.id)
    }
```

Now what I want is to give reference to the search view which is define in xml file like this

```
<record id="view_land_plots_search" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">land.plot.search</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Land Plots">
            <group expand="1" string="Group By">
                <filter string="Stage" name='stage_id' context="{'group_by': 'stage_id'}"/>
            </group>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

I don't know how to initialize search_view_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference to any record created using xml from within Odoo python code can be done using the records `xml_id` and `self.env.ref()` method.

In this case the `xml_id` of your search view record is `your_module_name.view_land_plots_search`. So the python code will be:

```
'search_view_id': self.env.ref('your_module_name.view_land_plots_search').id,
'context': "{'search_default_filter_stage_id': 1}"
```

Don't forget to replace `your_module_name` with your custom module directory name.

```
<record id="view_land_plots_search" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">land.plot.search</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Land Plots">
            <group expand="1" string="Group By">
                <filter string="Stage" name='filter_stage_id' context="{'group_by': 'stage_id'}"/>
            </group>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Your solution work fine but the filter which i apply inside the referenced view is not working. What should I do so that the plots can be 'group by' by default.

Comment: You can't reference a filter in a view. If you want to auto activate a filter of that referenced view, you have to do that in your action's (returned dict) context by using key `search_default_my_filter` (my_filter is the `name` of your filter in the view) and value `1` to use it.

Comment: fixed previous typo, `xml_id` need to be in quotes instead of backquotes. Also changed filter name as it was matching with your field name. check now.

Comment: as @CZoellner mentioned, you need add `'search_default_filter_name': 1` in your action context. Also added to the answer code.

Comment: what's not working? turn on debug, on debug menu edit action and check if search view is assigned or not. also if facing any error, share stack trace

Comment: @arryph i added ` 'context': "{'search_default_filter_stage_id': 1}" `  but still the filter is not working.

Comment: @arryph there is no error but the filter is not working

Comment: check debug menu >> edit action, check if search view and context is existing it not

Comment: @arryph thanks man. problem solved. i was using wrong name for my_filter. that is `stage_id` and i was using `my_stage_id`